# Durable Functions orchestrations in Java fail with "The function invocation resulted in a null response"

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

When running through the [Azure Functions Java quickstart tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-java), I ran into the following exception while trying to execute my orchestrator function.

> 2022-06-23T06:30:19.172Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HelloCities. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: The function invocation resulted in a null response. This means that either the orchestrator function was implemented incorrectly, the Durable Task language SDK was implemented incorrectly, or that the destination language worker is not sending the function result back to the host.

**What does this error mean and how do I fix it?**

Here's the information about the Azure Functions Core Tools being used, which is shown in the output of the core tools:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3734 Commit hash: 61192bb28820be76916f85209916152801483456  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.1.4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few potential causes for this error:

1. An orchestration trigger function returned a `null` value directly to the trigger.
2. The language worker doesn't (yet) know how to handle return values from orchestration trigger functions, and thus always returns `null` value back to the host.

For context, Durable Functions orchestration and activity triggers are different from all other triggers because they support return values. No other trigger types in Azure Functions support this (you can return values as output bindings when using other trigger types, but not return values directly to the trigger itself). To support Durable Functions, language workers such as Java needed to add support for handling these return values. Only the latest versions of the Java workers have this support.

In this specific case, this error is happening because an older build of the Azure Functions Core Tools is being used. You can see from the output above that Azure Functions Core Tools **v3.0.3734** is installed. However, the minimum required version for Functions v3.x is **v3.0.4585**. When using Azure Functions v4.x, the minimum required version is **v4.0.4590**.

Upgrading to the latest version of the Functions Core tools will resolve this issue. Information about the various ways to install the Azure Functions Core Tools can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#v2).